# Check whether a number is single, double, or triple digit using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to implement a Bash script that checks whether the number given by the user is single/2-digit/3-digit. I can only use case..esac statement. The following program works fine for single digit but the reset of the cases doesn't execute.

```
echo -e "\n-----NUMBER CHECK-----"
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number: "
read num

case $num in 
  [0-9])
    echo -e "\nSINGLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;

  [10-99])
    echo -e "\nDOUBLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;

  [100-999])
    echo -e "\nTRIPLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;
  
  *)
    echo -e "\nInvalid Input!"
  ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '\n-----NUMBER CHECK-----\n\n'

read -rp 'Enter a number: ' num

case $num in
  [0-9])
    printf '\nSINGLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
    ;;
  [0-9][0-9])
    printf '\nDOUBLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
    ;;
  [0-9][0-9][0-9])
    printf '\nTRIPLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
    ;;
  *)
    printf >&2 '\nINVALID INPUT!'
    ;;
esac
```

An alternative is to use a regex pattern matching using the test `=~` operator if your version of bash supports it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '\n-----NUMBER CHECK-----\n\n'

read -rp 'Enter a number: ' num

if [[ $num =~ ^[[:digit:]]{1}$ ]]; then
  printf '\nSINGLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
elif [[ $num =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2}$ ]]; then
  printf '\nDOUBLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
elif [[ $num =~ ^[[:digit:]]{3}$ ]]; then
  printf '\nTRIPLE DIGIT NUMBER!'
else
  printf >&2 '\nINVALID INPUT!'
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd validate the input first.

```
case $num in
*[!0-9]*|????*) ;; # invalid input
?) ;;              # single digit
??) ;;             # double digit
???) ;;            # triple digit
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is a *character* class. The `-` for specifying ranges only handles characters, not integers. `[100-999]` is a character class with …

- the characters `1`, `0`
- the range `0-9`
- and the characters `9` and `9`

… so basically `[0-9]`.

As pointed out by [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840775/6770384), use `[0-9][0-9]` and `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative but hacked solution:

```
echo -e "\n-----NUMBER CHECK-----"
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number: "
read num

case $num in
    *[!0-9]*|????*) good=0 ;;
    *) good=1;
esac

case 1 in
  $((good == 1 && num <= 9)))
    echo -e "\nSINGLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;

  $((good == 1 && num <= 99)))
    echo -e "\nDOUBLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;

  $((good == 1 && num <= 999)))
    echo -e "\nTRIPLE DIGIT NUMBER!"
  ;;

  *)
    echo -e "\nInvalid Input!"
  ;;

esac
```

Comment: Nice (hacky) idea. But for the input `word` this prints `SINGLE DIGIT NUMBER` because `word` is interpreted as a variable which is (in my case) uninitialized and therefore interpreted as `0`. Also, for input like `.:/...` you get a syntax error.